# Historization of a database model

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I develop a recommendation engine which gives recommendations for a specific product configuration of an user with certain attributes.

The following figure shows a simplified ER model of my application without historization.
The application has basically the two methods:

```
ComputeRecommendation:
   Input: [UserID, Properties (optional)], [ConfigID, Properties]
   Output: -

   Desc: Stores the user and configuration in the database and creates
         a recommendation which is also stored in the database.

GetRecommendation
   Input: [UserID, ConfigID]
   Output: [Recommendation]

   Desc: Returns the latest recommendation for the given user id and configuration id.
```

Link to figure 1: http://i62.tinypic.com/2d4zls.jpg

I want to add historization to the database model in order to keep track of all recommendations. So it is possible to see which user property and configuration property combination led to which recommendation and if a recommended property is added to a later version of the configuration.

The database should be fast for the mentioned two methods. Other selects for example to evaluate the quality of the recommendations are not time critical. Additionally the content of the database is loaded to an other database or into HDFS where it is analyzed to improve the recommendation engine. So actually the above database only needs the latest data.

I came up with the following extension. Current is an boolean flag to indicate the latest entry.

Link to figure 2: http://i62.tinypic.com/6t3ccz.jpg

**Questions:**

1. What is the right approach to add historization to the database model.
2. Is MySQL the right choice if the attributes of an user and the properties of a configuration would be nested JSON objects?

Comment: A good way to store fast a lot of data with historation (versioning) is to use a NoSQL database. If you prefer MySQL, I would do the versioning with triggers. Triggers are a bit tricky to develop and debug, but they are fast and rock solid.

Comment: @Joerg What NoSQL database would you recommend for this use case?

Comment: I like CouchDB because of 3 reasons: 1. Easy for local installation, developing, testing, just one application. 2. There are really good and fast providers for CouchDB 3. There is a client implementation (PouchDB), which I use for syncing the CouchDB with my Cordova/Phonegap apps.